# Setting hover for items in recyclerview

Tags: android, hover, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I have a listview in that I have recylerview of cardviews...when i select any of them then a floating layout should be there which has 3 buttons. I am using this library [enter link description here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover).

I am using this library in a adapter and have set that adapter in the activity, but as soon i go to activity the app crashes with **NullPointerException**. the error arises is that when i inflate two xml files but i want to inflate the **abc_card_view_video** first then clicking on any of it the new file **hover_card_view** should inflate but the old file should be in background.

help me get out of it. Thanks

```
     public class LessonVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LessonDataHolder> {

            private List<VideoList> slipList;
            private Context mContext;
            public BlurLayout samplelayout;


            public LessonVideoAdapter() {
                slipList = new ArrayList<>();
                slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 1", R.drawable.demo_one));
                slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 2", R.drawable.demo_two));
                slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 3", R.drawable.demo_one));

            }

            @Override
            public LessonDataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                Context context = parent.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_card_view_video, parent, false);
return new LessonDataHolder(view);          
  }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(LessonDataHolder holder, int position) {
                VideoList s = slipList.get(position);
                holder.bindSlip(s);

            }
            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return slipList.size();
            }
        }

        class LessonDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView nameOfSlip;
            private ImageView slipImage;
            private Context context;
            public LessonDataHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                context = itemView.getContext();
                nameOfSlip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.demoText);
                slipImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDemoVideo);

            }

            public void bindSlip(VideoList videoList) {
                nameOfSlip.setText(videoList.stringSlipName);
                slipImage.setImageResource(videoList.stringImage);
            }
        }

        class VideoList {
            public String stringSlipName;
            public int stringImage;

            public VideoList(String stringSlipName, int stringImage) {
                this.stringImage = stringImage;
                this.stringSlipName = stringSlipName;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should write this code in the listner of on click of items

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_card_view_video, parent, false);
    samplelayout = (BlurLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.blur_layout);
                View hover = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hover_card_view, null);
                samplelayout.setHoverView(hover);
```